# applying image augmentation on batch

Tags: tensorflow

how can I apply image augmentation functions such as `tf.image.random_flip_left_right` to a batch of images?

these functions require the input size to be of rank 3 (`[width, height, channels]`), while batched data has a rank of 4 (`[batch_size, width, height, channels]`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use tf.train.batch to build batches of images.

Take a look at how the CIFAR10 example processes its input:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_input.py

You can find a tutorial about the CIFAR10 example here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html

Hope that helps!